# How to compile gpu offloading code with icc

Tags: gpu, openmp, nvidia, icc

I compiled gpu offloading with gcc 11 on centos machine and executed on nvidia with offload of nvptx-none

I have icc 18 in my machine. How to compile my gcc offloading with icc and target of nvidia gpus.

what are the compiler options to do it ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would be 99.9999999% certain that there are none because that isn't supported by Intel's compilers

Comment: The Intel's solution for GPU offloading is basically to use OneAPI (made by... Intel).

Comment: but openmp4.5 will support icc17.0 onwards. so i m expecting there will be a way

Answer (score 0):

You can try using icx or other compilers instead :

Link to the documentation: https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/get-started-with-cpp-fortran-compiler-openmp/top.html#top_GUID-B965754E-4380-4B04-9377-8170E5030762